# Draw a check mark inside the rect tag in svg using js

Tags: javascript, svg

I have created a small rect using js and svg, here is the code for it:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<svg id="svgOne" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="5000" height="3000"> 
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

and js:

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var x = 50,
        y = 30;

var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '50');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '50');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'grey');
document.getElementById('svgOne').appendChild(rect);
```

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kzbwg/101/) is the jsfiddle.

I want to add a check mark inside the rectangle, the check mark looks like:

[image]

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Draw a [path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) that resembles the checkmark?

Comment: @FelixKling: Not sure about path and me knew to svg stuffs

Comment: You can click on the link in my previous comment to learn more about paths... it's a tutorial.

Comment: Or draw the checkmark in Inkscape or svg-edit and then see what markup it creates.

Comment: Why are you drawing it yourself with code?  If the idea is just to have a custom checkbox, it would be better to load the SVG from a predesigned file, then hide and show the check mark as necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the svg `path` element to crate your check mark. The tricky part about the `path` element is the `d` attribute, which will describe the path combining several instructions. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d) is some good information on how the `d` attribute works.

Take a look at the example and i'm sure you will get the idea.

```js
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var x = 50,
    y = 30;

// create group element
var group = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'g');
var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
// create the path element
var checkMark = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'path');

// set group position
group.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'translate('+ x + ', '+ y + ')');

rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '50');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '50');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'grey');
// set path attributes
checkMark.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', 'M7.375,33.25 c0,0,10,11.375,14.125,11.375S44.875,8,44.875,8');
checkMark.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'none');
checkMark.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linecap', 'round');
checkMark.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'stroke:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:6');

// append elements to group
group.appendChild(rect);
group.appendChild(checkMark);
// append group to svg
document.getElementById('svgOne').appendChild(group);

// clone your checkmark
var checkMarkCopy = group.cloneNode(true);
checkMarkCopy.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'translate(100, 100)');
document.getElementById('svgOne').appendChild(checkMarkCopy);
```

```html
<svg id="svgOne" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="5000" height="3000"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks now how would I group them? Meaning lets say I create many rectangles, I don't want path to me copied. Instead group rectangle and path together, so that I can make a copy of this group and move it other x,y co ordinates

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer, adding a group element.

Comment: Thanks, lets say I want to create a clone of them in say different x,y axis, how should I do that in js?

Answer (score 0):

When I executed the web page I got the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at: document.getElementById('svgOne').appendChild(group);

So I rearranged stuff according to what I learned from:
Saved from: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/creating-a-svg-element/5929/

ADDED: `<title>` in the `<head>` (not important at all).

MOVED: `</head>` to just after the `<title>`.

MOVED: `<body>` and `<h2>` to just after `</head>`.

ADDED: `<div id="container"/>` to `<body>`. //Will contain all of the SVG content.

NOTE: At this point, the container has been added to the `<body>` and the `<script>` is now positioned INSIDE the `<body>`.

DELETED the original SVG element from the : =>  `<svg id="svgOne" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="300"> </svg>`.

ADDED the creation of a new SVG element in the `<script>`:

```
var svg = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg"); //Create an svg tag in SVG's namespace
svg.setAttribute("width", "300");
svg.setAttribute("height", "400");
```

DELETED the original appendChild(group): =>  `document.getElementById('svgOne').appendChild(group);`

REPLACED it with the new appendChild(group):=>

```
svg.appendChild(group);
```

DELETED the original appendChild(checkMarkCopy): =>  `document.getElementById('svgOne').appendChild(checkMarkCopy);`

REPLACED it with the new appendChild(checkMarkCopy):=>

```
svg.appendChild(checkMarkCopy);
```

ADDED: =>  `document.getElementById("container").appendChild(svg);`

This worked in Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110.
In the Chrome console, the framework looks like:
[Framework of web page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhHir.jpg)